# JQuery hide specific text in element

Tags: jquery, text, hide

**Problem**

I need to hinde specific string in `td` element. But the problem is, that this `td` element also contains other tags, so I can't just go and erase this tag.

```
<td class="ms-list-addnew ms-textLarge ms-soften">
<a title="Saate sellesse loendisse või teeki lisada uue üksuse." class="ms-heroCommandLink" id="idHomePageNewItem" style="display: none;" onclick='NewItem2(event, "http://infoportaal2/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7BF4433171%2D98D5%2D414B%2D914F%2DAFD9A44BF869%7D&amp;RootFolder="); return false;' href="http://infoportaal2/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7BF4433171%2D98D5%2D414B%2D914F%2DAFD9A44BF869%7D&amp;RootFolder=" target="_self" data-viewctr="9">
<span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan16">
<img class="ms-list-addnew-img16" id="idHomePageNewItem-img" src="/_themes/42/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=44"></span>
<span>uus üksus</span>
</a> või selle loendi 
<a title="Saate seda loendit redigeerida kiirredigeerimisrežiimis." class="ms-heroCommandLink" onclick="EnsureScriptParams('inplview', 'InitGridFromView', '{32FA9EC5-6444-4ECC-9300-1D82D2AEB5F7}'); return false;" href="javascript:;">andmete sisestamine</a>
</td>
```

[image]

[image]

Note, that I used `$("#idHomePageNewItem").hide();` on first `<a>` element in this `td` element

**What I have tried**

I have tried to use following things:

```
$("td:contains('või selle loendi')").text().replace('või selle loendi', '');

$("span:contains('või selle loendi')").text().replace('või selle loendi', '');

$('div.text').text(function (i, t) {
    return t.replace('või selle loendi', '');
})
```

And some other similar variations. I have managed to delete whole content in tag (which would not work in my case) and a lot of nothing happening.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try indexOf?

```
if (td.html().indexOf("your string")>-1) {
  td.html(td.html().replace("your string",""));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. As I understand, then id need to get `td` with `var td = $("td:contains('või selle loendi')");` ?

Comment: `td` should be `var td = $("td")` of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

In the DOM, text content exists as text nodes. These are descendents of element nodes. Your problem is that jQuery is not set up well for manipulating text nodes: it is really based on elements.

It is, in my view, easier to deal with this in terms of native DOM functions:

```
let parent = document.querySelector('.ms-list-addnew');
// get all child nodes -- including text nodes
let childNodes = parent.childNodes;
// reduce array to contain only text nodes
let textNodes = Array.from(childNodes).filter(node => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE);
for (let node of textNodes) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace('või selle loendi', '');
}
```

Note that this is ES6 code and you may need to transpile it for older browsers.

It is also possible to do this in jQuery:

```
$('.ms-list-addnew')
  .contents()
  .filter(function(idx, node) {
    return node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
  })
  .each(function(idx, el) {
    el.nodeValue = el.nodeValue.replace('või selle loendi', '');
  });
```

Note that it is a *very bad idea* to replace the entire HTML or text content of the element. The latter will get rid of all the other elements and keep just the text, while the former will get rid of all existing event handlers and other data associated with the element but not rendered in HTML.